# What is the use of a reaction frame?

Tags: material-science, solid-mechanics

Many experiments I did in the structural mechanics lab had instruments placed inside a frame. For example, for verifying maxwell's reciprocal law, the instrument (that contained hydraulic pistons for applying loads at 2 points) was kept inside a frame. Similarly, the torsion testing equipment was also kept inside a frame. And this frame is also placed on top of a thick floor.

What will happen if the frame was absent and the experiments were carried out on top of plane ground? Why is it important to use a reaction frame to isolate the machine?

Comment: Are you able to find a picture of one - be nice to see.

Comment: It reduces mechanical noise, most likely, from people walking around etc, so that the measurements are mainly influenced by the undistorted signals you are interested in measuring.
LIGO, apparently is able to detect rabbits hopping around in fields a good distance away, as well as gravitational waves.